# setState in map function of react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-state-management

My Requirement is to update the state value in map function of componentWillReceiveProps.

In console log all I am getting is 1s but sub.subscribed contain 0s and 1s

Reference of console window: http://prntscr.com/jqifiz

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        regionAll: [],
      };
    }
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.apiData !== false ){
      nextProps.apiData.data.datacenter.category.map((sub)=> {
        console.log(sub.subscribed,'sub.subscribed');
        this.setState({
          regionAll: [
            ...this.state.regionAll,
            sub.subscribed
          ]
        },()=>{
          console.log(this.state.regionAll,'sub');
        })
      })
  }
```

Is this a correct way to update state in reactjs?

Comment: So what's the question

Comment: @ Isaac The set state is not updating properly

Comment: Your console snapshot print something ["1"] "sub". But i can see console.log(this.state.regionAll,'subbbb'); this statement . May be you are checking at different location. Your code seems fine

Comment: @stack26 Apologies I updated that code and replace subbb with sub

Comment: Console state is perfectly fine

Comment: I cannot see any problems in code. could you please , try consoling this.state.regionAll in render before return and share the snapshot of console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is async.In [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), it called multiple time.Only last value is added in array regionAll and not all because of async setState call with multiple value.

You can collect all `sub.subscribed` value in single array with [Array#reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) then perform state update.

```
if (nextProps.apiData !== false) {

    let sub = nextProps
        .apiData
        .data
        .datacenter
        .category
        .reduce((accum, sub) => [
            ...accum,
            sub.subscribed
        ], [])

    this.setState({
        regionAll: [...sub]
    }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.regionAll, 'sub');
    })
}
```

Comment: If I want to update the single value on all the state array. how to perform that? this.setState({ regionAll: true });

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because setState calls are batched and you are updated React state based on prevState, you should instead use functional state for such cases

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.apiData !== false ){
      nextProps.apiData.data.datacenter.category.map((sub)=> {
        console.log(sub.subscribed,'sub.subscribed');
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          regionAll: [
            ...prevState.regionAll,
            sub.subscribed
          ]
        }),()=>{
          console.log(this.state.regionAll,'sub');
        })
      })
  }
```

However its a bad idea to call setState in a map, you can instead get the data from map and call setState just once like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.apiData !== false ){
      const subscribed = nextProps.apiData.data.datacenter.category.map((sub)=> {
        console.log(sub.subscribed,'sub.subscribed');
        return sub.subscribed;
      })
      this.setState(prevState => ({
          regionAll: [
            ...this.state.regionAll,
            ...subscribed
          ]
        }),()=>{
          console.log(this.state.regionAll,'sub');
     })
  }
```